# Is there a way of finding what .NET classes implements a certain interface?

Tags: .net, inheritance, interface, class-hierarchy

For example if I wanted to see what my .NET options were for something implementing IList or IDictionary. Is there a way to find that for example in the MSDN documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find it in MSDN, I usually go to Google, type something like "MSDN IList", and to get to [IList Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(VS.71).aspx) which has a section "Classes that Implement IList". That's true for any of the interface classes.

If you find a base class such as [DictionaryBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionarybase(VS.71).aspx), there will be a link called *Derived Classes* which will take you to a tree showing the [inheritance hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa318018(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

I think it's possible using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Comment: Search for the interface in Reflector, and then expand the Derived Types under that interface.

Comment: Make sure you tell Reflector about all the assemblies that you are using. Otherwise, it won't be able to find those implementations.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this programmatically.

If you know the assembly where the types are located (I'm using `mscorlib` as that is where `string` is located) you can build a list using this method:

### .Net 3.0

```
List<Type> implementors = 
   Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(string))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IList)))
    .ToList();
```

### .Net 2.0

```
List<Type> implementors = new List<Type>();

foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(string)).GetTypes())
{
    foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (interfaceType == typeof(IList))
        {
            implementors.Add(type);
        }
    }
}
```

The `implementors` list will hold a list of of `Types` that implement the interface `IList`. You can change `IList` to any interface you'd like, `IDictionary`, `ICollection`, etc.

#### Edit:

If you want to extend this to all assemblies in the current `AppDomain`, you could do:

```
List<Type> implementors = 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()
                        .Where(type => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IList)))
            ).ToList();
```

It really all depends on what you're doing with the data. If you just want to view them for your own personal satisfaction, [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is going to be your easiest option - especially if you want to look beyond assemblies loaded in your application domain (assuming you have an application to begin with). I suppose you could load all the assemblies from the GAC in that case... but this is basically what [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) does except you get to pick and choose which ones you want individually.

Comment: Would be more difficult if having to take other assemblies into account as well... or are there a way of scanning through all assemblies that are considered part of the .Net Framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup the interfaces a certain type implements with this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx

Should do the trick

Comment: I think the question was asking for the opposite: all classes that implement a certain interface.

Comment: I need the other way around, kind of.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific use case? Off the top of my head you could use:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList (or derived)
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T> derived
System.Collections.CollectionBase derived
System.Collections.DictionaryBase derived
System.Collections.Hashtable (or derived)
```