# What is the best way to search for classes that implement a particular interface in .NET's FCL?

Tags: .net, interface, fcl

Yes, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134221/is-there-a-way-of-finding-what-net-classes-implements-a-certain-interface) was asked back in 2009 - almost 4 years ago.

However, it's no longer true that MSDN will show a list of "Classes that Implement *Interface*" in the FCL documentation.  Also, while I agree that Reflector is neat, it's also not free - which is not neat.  Shouldn't there be an easier way to check what classes in the FCL implement a particular interface by .NET version number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html) a free decompiler from JetBrains.

Here is a screenshot

[image: Inheritors]

Comment: Thanks Oleskii!  This method definitely works, but perhaps MS should be a little embarrassed that such functionality requires a download from a 3rd party.  We should be able to look up this information on MSDN in the FCL section.

Comment: Note that this will only show the types that implement the interface AND are loaded in dotPeek. If an assembly is not loaded by dotPeek it will not be searched for implementing types.